# What is the reason for the error A is not a subtype of B

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently started learning Clean Architecture from a video tutorial. I tried to repeat after the mentor, but only for my own project. As a result, I ran into an error - Unhandled Exception: type 'HotSalesEmpty' is not a subtype of type 'HotSalesLoading' in type cast.

> Error text - [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled
> Exception: type 'HotSalesEmpty' is not a subtype of type
> 'HotSalesLoading' in type cast E/flutter (5494): #0
> HotSalesCubit.loadHotSales.
> (package:architecture/features/presentation/cubit/hot_sales_list_cubit.dart:20:31)
> E/flutter (5494): #1 Right.fold (package:dartz/src/either.dart:200:64)
> E/flutter (5494): #2
> HotSalesCubit.loadHotSales(package:architecture/features/presentation/cubit/hot_sales_list_cubit.dart:19:23)
> E/flutter ( 5494):

Here is the code by going to the first link and the third link -

```
failureOrHotSales.fold((error) => HotSalesError(message: _mapFailureToMessage(error)), (character) {
      final hotSales = (state as HotSalesLoading).oldHotSalesList;
      hotSales.addAll(character);
      emit(HotSalesLoaded(hotSales));
    });
```

I think this code will also be useful -

```
class HotSalesLoading extends HotSalesState {
  final List<HotSalesEntity> oldHotSalesList;

  const HotSalesLoading(this.oldHotSalesList); //Loading characters

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [oldHotSalesList];
}
```

and HotSalesEmpty -

```
class HotSalesEmpty extends HotSalesState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Comment: Where and how is is `HotSalesEmpty` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing now.. But I suspect that `HotSalesEmpty` is defined as:

`class HotSalesEmpty extends HotSalesState { ...`

This means that `HotSalesEmpty` is not a subtype of `HotSalesLoading`, but a subtype of `HotSalesState`.

Before you do this type cast: `(state as HotSalesLoading)` you could wrap it with a check first:

```
if (state is HotSalesLoading) {
  final hotSales = (state as HotSalesLoading).oldHotSalesList;
....
}
```

Comment: Yes, the errors are gone, but... I don't see anything on the screen now. I added code where i create class HotSalesEmpty

Comment: But thanks, now I have less of a problem!